# How to check if process is ended & Start it again even with Console Application Hidden

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm making a parental program and I'm trying to make the process persistent so that the child cannot end the process. However my code works when the console application is showing but when I hide it using:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

Its like my code to check if its closed never runs which then doesn't Process.start the application again.

Any ideas how to make Console application C# Process Persistent? Even if the window is hidden? share your thoughts feedback required.

Comment: Does it have to be a "console" application with the Window? Maybe you could make it a windows service and use the recovery options provided to services

Comment: Could you explain what you mean a bit more?

Comment: It would be a good idea to explain why it has to be a console application or if that is just what you picked for no particular reason. A windows service runs in the background with some level of protection against crashes by having restart options. Take a look at the TopShelf project (http://topshelf-project.com/) as a starting point to windows services.

Comment: It has to be a console application since I have coded for it. I'm just going to make two console applications that mirror eachother.